# Accept nil argument only is instance variable is set

Tags: ruby

I want to create a function that requires a value, unless it already had an instance value created. However, I don't want to make the argument `nil` by default, and instead want it to instead gracefully know whether or not it needs to accept an argument. For example,

```
def config(c)
    @config ||= c
end
```

would return `@config` if I called it, but will give a `ArgumentError` when I attempt to call it without an argument. Can I make the function not require an argument is the instance variable exists?

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You want it to default to some (non-nil) value (when the argument is not given) (until the value is set). On the other hand, you want to make the argument obligatory until the value is set. That is impossible. -1 and voted to close.

Comment: @sawa It’s not impossible, just have to throw away the default sometimes.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall When is the default value used at all?

Comment: @sawa Okay, so all the time. But does it matter? You’re using it to allow a variable number of arguments. The point is it *is* possible, just have to be a bit creative perhaps.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I don't understand it at all.

Comment: The main reason I want to do something like this is that I don't want to create a function, such as `config()` that accepts a parameter and sets the configuration in `@config`. I want to later call this in other functions, i.e. `config[name]` to get certain configuration values, but I want to ensure that the configuration exists first. @Andrew Marshall, am I thinking of this issue in a weird/roundabout way and can do it differently?

Comment: Your comment is also contradictory. How can it be that you want to later call a function that you don't want to create?

Comment: I mistyped. I meant "that I want to create a function, such as...", instead of "that I don't want to...". Anyway, Andrew Marshall has answered my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby doesn’t provide any facility to do this, but why not just raise ArgumentError yourself like so:

```
def config(c = nil)
  raise ArgumentError unless c || @config
  @config ||= c
end
```

Alternatively, Ruby 2.0 sort of provides something like this with its keyword arguments:

```
class A
  def config c: (@config or raise ArgumentError)
    @config = c
  end
end

a = A.new
a.config        #=> ArgumentError
a.config(c: 2)  #=> 2
a.config        #=> 2
```

Of course, maybe what you really should do is just use a normal setting method (i.e. `def config=(value) ...`) or simply `attr_accessor :config`. That is, in your basic example at least, the most idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: This is a much better solution to what I was wanting to do. I just wanted a setter and getter function but didn't know what to call it, so I was looking to create a solution for the wrong problem. I didn't think about `attr_accessor` or `def config=`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you need to avoid defaulting the argument to nil, but to get functionality you specified:

'It needs to raise an Argument error if no argument is passed in and the instance variable is not set, but allow it to be called without an argument if the instance variable is set.'

This will work:

```
def config(c=nil)
  raise ArgumentError if c.nil? && @config.nil?
  @config ||= c
end
```

Yes, I am defaulting the argument to nil, which you asked to avoid, but if the argument is nil then we short circuit and raise an error if @config isn't set and if @config is set, it doesn't matter if the argument is nil since the next line will just return @config.

Comment: I like Andrew's c || @config as it reads nicer than my nil checks.

Comment: Except that Andrew's answer blacklists false as well as nil, which may or may not be okay.

Comment: Of course if you expect `false` to be a value, then one should use your way as mine won’t work quite right.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `*` before the argument:

```
def config(*c)
    @config ||= c
end
```

Note however that you will now get multiple values for `c` if you run: `config('hi', 'hello')` apart from that it will work.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without defining it as `nil`? I don't want to make the argument `nil` by default.

Comment: @Mosselman The problem is that now it defaults to being an empty array if you don't provide an argument.  You could fix that by making the assignment `@config ||= (c.length > 1 ? c : c.shift)`

Comment: It was either nil or []. He didn't want `nil` so here we are.